# How to read, process variable POST, Python HTTP Server

Tags: python, http, post, server

**Server code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import BaseHTTPServer
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import SocketServer
import urlparse
import cgitb
import cgi
from cgi import parse_header, parse_multipart


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
 def _set_headers(self):
  self.send_response(200)
  self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
  self.end_headers()

 def do_GET(self):
   self._set_headers()
   self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>hi!</h1></body></html>")

 def do_HEAD(self):
   self._set_headers()

 def do_POST(self):
  ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
  if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
   postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
  elif ctype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
   length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
   postvars = cgi.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length), keep_blank_values=1)
  else:
   postvars = {}

def run(server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=80):
 server_address = ('', port)
 httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
 print 'Starting httpd...'
 httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":

        run()
```

**Clinet**

Client send POST request over program Postman.

GET works.

Post is does not work . This is Error on server when I send request

http://192.168.2.108?var1=value

**ERROR ON SERVER**

> Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.2.107',
>   49629) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in
>   _handle_request_noblock
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in **init**
>       self.handle()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
>       self.handle_one_request()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 328, in
>   handle_one_request
>       method()   File "server.py", line 37, in do_POST
>       ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 309, in parse_header
>       parts = _parseparam(';' + line) TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: What does `self.headers.getheader('content-type')` return?

Comment: Why did you make the exception text unreadable again? Instead of making it hard to read the exception you could spend your time printing the content-type to see if its really in the header or returning None. If `parse_header` is erroring because of `None`, there is a significant chance that you are passing in a `None`.

Comment: Thank you tdelaney. Problem was in Postman. 
probably I set wrong values. Post works on  Android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because the request sent by your client does not include the content-type header.

You did not say how you are connecting to the server.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8880/?var1=value
```

Will fail as shown above. While:

```
 curl -X POST http://localhost:8880/?var1=value -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Will fail also, but a bit further along the way: you also need a *Content-length* header. What you need is to check the values returned to you by the class methods instead of trusting everything will happen as you wish it will:

```
def do_POST(self):
    content_type = self.headers.getheader('content-type')
    if content_type is None:
        raise ... # 400 Invalid Request

    # otherwise go on.
```

Comment: Thanks for advice it was solutions. But i dont know why content-lenght is empty.  **if content_lenght is None: print "empty"**

Comment: @user7432329 Maybe because when the `Content-type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the query is expected to contain a body (see curl's man page and in particular its `-d` switch). That's why you need to use the `POST` and not `GET` method.